# 1669. Merge In Between Linked Lists - Leetcode - failing test

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am working on the LeetCode problem [1669. Merge In Between Linked Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-in-between-linked-lists):

> You are given two linked lists: `list1` and `list2` of sizes `n` and `m` respectively.
>
> Remove `list1`'s nodes from the `a`<sup>th</sup> node to the `b`<sup>th</sup> node, and put `list2` in their place.
>
> The blue edges and nodes in the following figure indicate the result:
>
> [image]
>
> *Build the result list and return its head.*
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> ```
> 3 <= list1.length <= 10⁴
> 1 <= a <= b < list1.length - 1
> 1 <= list2.length <= 10⁴
> ```

Here is my code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeInBetween(self, list1: ListNode, a: int, b: int, list2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        
        slow = fast = list1
        temp1 = temp2 = list2

        slowslow = fastfast = list1

        if slow != a:
            slow = slow.next

        if slowslow.val != a-1:
            slowslow = slowslow.next

        if fast != b:
            fast = fast.next
            fastfast = fast.next

        while temp2.next:
            temp2 = temp2.next

        slowslow.next = temp1
        temp2.next = fastfast

        return list1
```

It fails with the first test case:

Input:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
3
4
[1000000,1000001,1000002]
```

MyOutput :

```
[0,1000000,1000001,1000002,2,3,4,5]
```

Expected Output:

```
[0,1,2,1000000,1000001,1000002,5]
```

I am trying to place the `slowslow` pointer before `a`, and `fastfast` pointer after `b`, and then connect `slowslow` to `temp1` and `temp2` to `fastfast`.

But somehow that is not working. What is wrong in my attempt?

I am new to linked lists and would appreciate a simple change or even a simpler alternative method.

Comment: The first problem that immediately shows is that you are comparing nodes with ints. That cannot be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- `slow != a` is a condition that is always False because `slow` is a `ListNode` object, and `a` is an `int`. The same problem occurs with `fast != b`.
- `slowslow.val != a-1` is wrong, as there is nothing in the question that requires to look at the *values* in the list. `a` is an *index*, not a *value*.
- Your code will set `slow` to either the first node or the second node of the first list. There is no loop that guarantees that `slow` will reference the node before index `a`. The same problem exists for `fast`.

Here is working code:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeInBetween(self, list1: ListNode, a: int, b: int, list2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        # Find node that precedes index a in first list
        left = list1
        for i in range(a - 1):
            left = left.next
        # Find node that follows index b in first list
        right = left
        for i in range(b - a + 2):
            right = right.next
        # Find tail node of second list            
        tail = list2
        while tail.next:
            tail = tail.next
        # Make the connections
        left.next = list2
        tail.next = right
        return list1
```

Comment: you're ignoring lots of edge cases here (not list1, not list2, a > len(list) etc)

Comment: Those edge cases are excluded in the LeetCode problem. It is intended. See the "constraints" section.